# Problems with copy constructor and vector

Tags: c++, constructor

I met a problem with copy constructor and vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class B {
private:
    int val;
};

class A {
private:
    B b;
public:
    A() {}
    A(A& a) {}
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    A aa;
    A a2 = aa;//it works well
    //addA(va, aa);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class B {
private:
    int val;
};

class A {
private:
    B b;
public:
    A() {}
    A(A& a) {}
};

void addA(std::vector<A>& va, A a) {
    va.push_back(a);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<A> va;
    A aa;
    A a2 = aa;
    addA(va, aa); // I got a compile error
    return 0;
}
```

there is a compiler error.

But if I change the args in class `A`'s copy constructor to `const A&`, it works well.

Why is this so?

Comment: This is an odd looking copy constructor signature A(A& a), why do you allow the object to be copy to be changed? The only class with that signature was auto_ptr and we all know how much confusion has created.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `std::vector<A>::push_back` is `const A &`, so when the vector tries to copy that into the storage it allocated for the element, it requires a constructor that takes `const A &`. Because yours doesn't, it can't be used.